# Integrating JWT based authorization flow with OAuth in Flask

Tags: python, flask, oauth, jwt, facebook-login

I have REST API in Flask running on Heroku with JWT based authorization flow feeding users with standard access and refresh token approach. I want to add Facebook OAuth access token flow along with standard JWT. The idea is to attach Facebook's access token in the header by the clients (by those logged with Facebook button) instead of JWT (those using normal flow) in all @jwt-required endpoints in the app. The flask will then recognize it is not the JWT but OAuth and make a HTTP request with it to the Facebook Graph API getting the profile id thus confirming the validity of the token and making the necessary changes for the user in the database. Is it possible within flask? I would appreciate any suggestions how to proceed with the idea or maybe change the approach.